# How to find the right questions that I can answer?

Tags: discussion

I believe most people do it using tags. Surely some use the "newest questions" link above, or the others filtering options. Others just attack them randomly when they're feeling a thrust of need to answer questions. And there are others who come across questions for whatever reason (such as google) to eventually give an answer.

I don't have a method, but I see there are way too many unanswered questions. There's probably at least one question that I could answer, but I'm finding it quite difficult to find the ones that are "right for me."

So, what do you do to find your answerable questions?

Comment: Generally, the best way to search is always through filter, tags are often not efficient enough.

Comment: Basically... I hope I'm lucky to spot one in the pile. There is only so much time I can spend looking for one. And that is even when I applied Mike Slinn's excellent advice of setting up tag exclusions; you're not only looking for questions that you can answer but also questions which *deserve to be answered*; there is no filter for that. More often than not I get no further than ask a few questions in comments to try and get a question body improved to a point where it can be answered by someone, or to find a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any time I see topics that do not interest me I filter them out. I also follow topics that do interest me. There are some times of day and some days that have more questions than others. Your mileage may vary, so just keep a log of when you found interesting questions, and soon a pattern will emerge. You will know when to look then.

The bounties might take longer (some are quick), one strategy might be to favor them. They tend to be more stable, take your time with them.

Another strategy might be to look for old unanswered questions.

Another is to reload the page of new listings frequently.

A better question I think is: why do this? Your answer to that question may provide self-guidance on how to do it.

Answer (score -7):

If you want to help other members on Stack Overflow and achieve everything you are interested in then here is the URL you must start at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions

Use the filter out there to find find the appropriate topic you are interested in at a time.
[image: usefull filter]

That's it!